# android detect network connection when network is connected but network is not reachable

Tags: android, android-networking

I developed an android app which is now in use by actual users, but they are complaining that services are failing frequently. When I investigating on this issue, I came to know that issue is because of week network.

**Explanation of the issue:** sometimes even though network is there in their mobiles, internet strength is not good. so, services are failing when internet strength is poor.

**Question:** How to identify internet strength on android mobiles.

**My explores on this issue:** I went to some interior place with my personal mobile and I could see internet symbols (3G/H) on mobile, but I was unable to search in mobile browser, whereas I was able to make a voice call.

**Note:** I have a logic in my app to indicate network offline when we try to make a service call. Likewise, I have to indicate that network strength is poor.

Comment: if slow connection is there, I believe that you get RequestTimeOut Error, NetworkError. simple catch those and show a proper message.

Comment: @skadoosh, Yes, I agree with you. But there are some push request also which requires good signal strength. So, users are expecting some notification about internet strength.